# HTTP 403 Forbidden Error with IdHTTP1.Get

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a program that gets data from a txt file hosted at iPage. (http://cpcheats.co/stuff/itemids.txt) It worked fine, until I switched hosts. Now, when I run the program it has a HTTP 403 Forbidden error. I checked .htaccess and there's nothing that would stop the access to it. The permissions are 644. The code is:

```
raw:=TStringList.create;
raw.AddStrings(Pickle.explode(#10,IdHTTP1.Get('http://cpcheats.co/stuff/itemids.txt')));
SetLength(items,raw.Count);
for i:=0 to raw.Count-1 do
  begin
    temp:=copy(raw[i],1,FastCharPos(raw[i],',',1)-1);
    items[i]:=temp;
    raw[i]:=stringreplace(raw[i],temp+',','',[]);
  end;
combobox1.Items:=raw;
combobox1.Text:='Choose igloo';
```

(Pickle.explode works the same as explode in PHP) I don't think the problem is in the code, because it worked fine until I switched hosts. Another thing is that it worked fine when using file_get_contents in PHP to retrieve data from that file, but it doesn't work in a Delphi program.

Comment: Please don't put information in the subject line you can supply in tags instead. The tagging system works extremely well here organizing questions into the proper topics, and doesn't need help. :-) Thanks.

Comment: You have not provided any information about the TIdHTTP property settings, if/where you are initializing its username/password, what kind of authentication scheme(s) the server supports/expects, if you have any IdAuthentication units in your uses clause, etc.  Need more details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too , since May 2013 ,before that it works fine for years .

finally I add the line  below before IdHTTP1,get ,and it works now

IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent:='Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; Maxthon)';

To tell the truth  I don't know what really happen  still .

Comment: Some web servers send different content to different user agents. Some servers do not recognize TIdHTTP's default user agent. So you are telling TIdHTTP to claim it is Internet Explorer instead, which tends to work better. I suggest you contact the admin for the affected webserver and find out what changed in May and why it no longer works correctly for some user agents.